# I'm trying to do simple multiplication in order to afterwards place it in a variable

Tags: python, math

code:

```
if item_id == 1:
    price = int(500)
    Quantity = int(input("How much do you want?"))
    total = Quantity * price
    if total < money:
        print("You have successfully bought this item.")
        money - total
```

Just saying, if this helps, I use repl.it, an online code environment.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to put an output of a equation (multiplication) in a variable

Comment: does that clarify it?

Comment: `total = Quantity * price` isn't working? Open up a python interpreter and type that in with the two variables defined.

Comment: The problem with the code is that the result of `money  - total` is discarded. My guess was that you wanted to update money... but that's subtraction, not multiplication. Can you tell us which line you are having problems with?

Comment: And `money` is not defined!

Comment: this is only a snippet of code money was defined before

Comment: as i was saying, i used repl.it, an online repl, it displayed it as wrong

Comment: also the multiplication part is when im trying to get the total of well,* total*  *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to update `money`, so just reassign the result of the subtraction back to `money`.

```
money = money - total
```

Python has a shortcut operator you could use instead.

```
money -= total
```